# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' - angular8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

In Component I Have

```
  @Input() CaseFormIn: FormGroup;
get f() { return this.CaseFormIn.controls; }
```

In Template

```
 <div class="error-message" *ngIf="this.f.generalInfoFormGroup.controls.primaryStore.touched&&this.f.generalInfoFormGroup.controls.primaryStore.errors">
           Primary Store is a Required Field.
        </div>
```

in development code is working fine but getting below error in prod mode
 Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

```
get primaryStore() { return (this.CaseFormIn.controls.generalInfoFormGroup as FormGroup).controls.primaryStore; }
```

and in template

```
 <div class="error-message" *ngIf="primaryStore.touched && primaryStore.errors">
      Primary Store is a Required Field.
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular show this kind of problem when u have mistake in code.
Sometimes there is no info...
Also good practice is doing multiple getters for controls.